# Need to show workdays in each month as well as the workdays per year

Tags: date, ssms

In SSMS, I need to produce output that shows the current month, total workdays in the current month, what workday number the current date is in the current month, as well as the total workday per year and the what workday the current date is in the current year. From that, the current monthly Plan will be divided by the total month workdays, then that amount * the workdays to date for the month. Along with that, there should be a YTD Plan that totals each completed months plan then adds the current month daily plan amount * current months workdays to date. Hopefully I have explained this well enough that it's understandable.

Here is the example of what I have but it is only getting me halfway there.I'm having trouble with the yearly part, as well as displaying more than the current month.

```sql
;with dates as(
    select dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())) as startofmonth,
    dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(m,1,dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())))) as endofmonth,
    DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) as startofyear,
     DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1) AS endofyear,
     convert(date,getdate()) as today
)
,holidays as (
    select holiday from (values ('2023-01-01'),('2023-01-16'),('2023-02-20'),('2023-04-07'),('2023-05-29'),('2023-06-19'),('2023-07-04'),('2023-09-04'),('2023-11-23'),('2023-12-25')) t(holiday)
)                 
,holidaycount as (
    select count(*) as holidaysinmonth,
        sum(case when holiday<=today then 1 else 0 end) as holidaystodate
    from dates
    join holidays on holiday between startofmonth and endofmonth
)
,daycounts as(
    select dates.*,

       (DATEDIFF(dd, startofmonth, endofmonth) + 1)
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, startofmonth, endofmonth) * 2)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startofmonth) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, endofmonth) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      -isnull(holidaysinmonth,0) as wkdaysinmonth,

       (DATEDIFF(dd, startofmonth, today) + 1)
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, startofmonth, today) * 2)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startofmonth) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, today) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      -isnull(holidaystodate,0) as wkdaystodate,

        (DATEDIFF(dd, startofyear, endofyear) + 1)
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, startofyear, endofyear) * 2)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startofyear) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, endofyear) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      -isnull(holidaysinmonth,0) as wkdaysinyear,

       (DATEDIFF(dd, startofyear, today) + 1)
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, startofyear, today) * 2)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startofyear) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, today) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      -isnull(holidaystodate,0) as wkdaystodateyr

    from dates
    cross join holidaycount
) 

--select * from daycounts

select   
     68933300/wkdaysinmonth) as DailyPremiumPlan,
     sum(689333000/wkdaysinmonth*wkdaystodate) as MTDPremiumPlan,
      wkdaysinmonth,
     wkdaystodate,
    wkdaysinyear,
    wkdaystodateyr

 from   daycounts dc 
  group by  wkdaystodateyr,wkdaysinyear, wkdaystodate,wkdaysinmonth
```

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

Comment: It's also not clear what your question is here. You state some requirements and provide your attempt, but don't actually ask anything or explain what isn't working about your attempt  (just that you are "struggling"). We can't run your query, we don't have acces to your environment, so we can't see why the values you get aren't what you expect.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm using SQL Server My issue is, I can only figure out how to get the data for one month at a time. I took out the database specifics in the query so this will show what the results for the current month are. I am trying to get this same information for each month of the year in one output. If the month is complete, the wkdaystodate should show the same as the wkdaysinmonth. If the month hasn't started yet, the wkdaystodate should be null. I cannot figure out how to do this